# How the heck can I fix this Brick texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing, modifiers, uv, node-editor

I've made simple unwrap, I haven't applied solidify  and boolean modifiers yet. Most problem is in this window frame. I've moved,scaled, rotated texture  already but  mortar or size of bricks didn't match up. Even tried UV projection modifier but all for nothing(

[image: See the image below]
[image: Wall]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi :). To match texel density across multiple UV islands, you can use an addon: [Texel Density Checker](https://gumroad.com/l/CEIOR)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can fix this without applying the modifiers. The only real geometry you have are the 2 planes that create the walls and only for these planes you can create a UV map. And the UV map is needed to map the texture properly, especially for the inside of the window.

Comment: @Blunder: I think so too, but wait for Robin with his procedural solution and just 1024 nodes…

Comment: Thanks, I've found out the solution already, as you mentioned I just applied  boolean modifier and it fixed this issue